# How to fetch two dependent requests in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to use two fetch requests in vue. The first request is fetching product data. The second request then should fetch with the product name from the first request the number of variants.

The first request is working fine. Also the second is working, but somehow the number of variants is always 0.

The strange thing is that with console.log the number is correct. But the log from the first fetch always says: numberOfVariants: undefined. So, I wander if the second fetch is not finishing in time. What could I do? I thought of computed properties. Please see the output and code below.

```
numberOfVariants: undefined
app.js:69 results: [{"id":"1562329837","name":"Klinares"},{"id":"1327067005","name":"Chair Keny"}]
app.js:30 getProductNumberOfVariants OK: 8
app.js:42 variants: 8

Const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            topsellers: [],
            imageDir: 'https://item.images.de/',
            // numberOfVariants: 0,
            variants: 0
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // variants() {
        //     return 21;
        // },
        // numberOfVariants() {
        //     return {
        //         amount: 3
        //     }
        // }
    },
    methods: {
        getProductNumberOfVariants(name) {
            let name2 = name.replaceAll(' ', '-');
            let variants;
            // let name2 = name.split(' ').join('-');
            fetch('https://dev.local/get-product-number-of-variants/' + name2).then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log("getProductNumberOfVariants OK: " + data);
                this.variants = data;
                console.log("variants: " + this.variants);
                // return 22;
                return this.variants;
            });
        },
        loadTopseller(category) {
            fetch('https://dev.local/get-topseller-by-category/' + category).then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            }).then((data) => {
                this.topsellers = data;
                const results = [];
                for (const d of data) {
                    var numberOfVariants = this.getProductNumberOfVariants(d.name);
                    console.log("numberOfVariants: " + numberOfVariants);
                    // variantsNumber = variantsNumber();
                    // console.log(variantsNumber);
                    results.push({
                        id: d.id,
                        name: d.name,
                        variants: numberOfVariants
                    })
                    // console.log("result: " + results);
                }
                console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
            });
        }
    }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

The previously referenced answer did not solved my problem.

I have even removed the second fetch request from the first one like this:

```
loadTopseller(category) {
        fetch('https://dev.local/get-topseller-by-category/' + category).then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            this.topsellers = data;
            // console.log("topsellers: " + JSON.stringify(this.topsellers));
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

And then call the second fetch request in the template:

```
<div v-for="(topseller, index) in topsellers" class="col preview-box mt-2">
            <img class="box-image" v-bind:src="imageDir+topseller.product_image+'_'+topseller.savecode+topseller.endung"
                 v-bind:alt="topseller.name">
            <span>{{ topseller.name }}</span>
            <div id="variants-Available" v-if="topsellers.length < index">{{ getProductNumberOfVariants(topseller.name) }}
                + <?php echo ' ' . $arr_lang['varianten']; ?>
            </div>
```

But the div with the variants id="variants-Available" is either not shown or the loop is executed too many times. the number of the variants is not shown at all or it is always counting up. How can the v-for only be looped through one time and show the correct number of variants?
Is it fine to fetch the variants in a second fetch in the v-if?

Comment: You can chain the fetch requests - they are using Promises. Simply feed the second with the result from the first.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have added the second request in the second promise. Now it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with what you have currently.
First of all, you're not waiting for your `fetch` requests to resolve in the `for` loop before pushing it into the `results` array.

Another problem is you're making multiple requests to `getProductNumberOfVariants` (one for each seller) but each of those calls write their result into the same instance property: `variants`. Which means they keep overwriting the result and you'll only see the last one to have returned.

Here's what would work:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    category: String
  },
  data: () => ({
    topSellers: [],
    variants: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.loadTopSellers(this.category).then(() => {
      // here this.topSellers and this.variants are already populated:
      console.log({
        sellers: this.topSellers,
        variants: this.variants
      })
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getProductNumberOfVariants({ name }) {
      const url = `https://dev.local/get-product-number-of-variants/${
        name.replaceAll(' ', '-')
      }`;
      return fetch(url).then(r => {
        if (r.ok) {
          return r.json()
        } else {
          this.log(url)
          return null
        }
      })
    },
    loadTopSellers(category) {
      const url = `https://dev.local/get-topseller-by-category/${category}`;
      return fetch(url).then(r => {
        if (r.ok) {
          return r.json()
        } else {
          this.log(url)
          return []
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.topSellers = data
        return Promise.all(
          data.map(this.getProductNumberOfVariants)
        ).then(r => {
          this.variants = r
        })
      })
    },
    log(url) {
      console.error(`Call to ${url} failed!`)
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

**Important note**: Apart from using `Promise.all()`, the most important part is that I'm returning the `fetch` call (which is a promise) to `Promise.all()` and when all of them have returned, the results will be assigned to `this.variants`. Note the `variants` will have the same order as the `sellers`, even if the promises (which run in parallel) resolve in a different order.